# Writing an image/swf onto page from external script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently messing around with some code for an advertising network, i have the main PHP back end complete but am struggling with the actual serving of the advert/image/swf.

I have tried using document.write, but this seems to get rid of the whole body, which is expected. However, looking at other ad networks code, it seems some use this to.

I have tried creating an element;

```
 var element = document.createElement('div');

 element.innerHTML = '<a href="'+url+'"><img src="'+path+'"></a>';
```

Does anyone have any idea how i can write the advert into the page, where the ad code was placed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it currently and it works just fine:

This is the code I offer to users to put on their websites

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite.com/serve.php"></script>
```

And in serve.php I just simply echo the ad image I want wrapped in an `<a>` tag

```
document.write('<a href="<?php echo $redirect_url ?>" target="blank"><img src="<?php echo $imageFile ?>" border="0" /></a>');
```

Comment: The problem is, document.write removes the body of the web page.

Comment: How can that be even possible?

Comment: Because thats what document write does, do you have a link where you are using this?